# How to access Azure VM from AzureDevOps Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, wildfly

I have a Wildfly application that runs inside a VM in azure. I would like to access my azure VM by ssh to deploy a wildlfy with command mvn deploy. I already have a service connection with azure resource mananger, how can i connect in vm? I can use azure CLI, but the ssh it's only to a public ip, i need to connect by de private ip, my vm dont have access to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

By default, DevOps Pipelines run on Microsoft-hosted pipeline agents, which do not reside in your private VNET. For this scenario, build and run your own Azure DevOps agents on VMs or containers within your VNET where your target VM resides. Configure the pipeline to execute on your self-hosted agents and the pipeline tasks will be able to reach your VM, since they are executing on the same VNET.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install